# PySpark problem flattening array with nested JSON and other elements

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

I'm struggling with the correct syntax to flatten some data.

I have a `dlt` table with a column (named `lorem` for the sake of the example) where each row looks like this:

```
[{"field1": {"field1_1": null, "field1_2": null}, 
  "field2": "blabla", "field3": 13209914, 
  "field4": {"field4_1": null, "field4_2": null}, "field5": 4}, ...
]
```

I want my output to create a new table based on the first that basically creates a row per each element in the array I shared above.

Table should look like:

```
|field1_1|field1_2|field2|field3|field4_1|field4_2|field_5|
|:-------|:-------|:-----|:-----|:-------|:-------|:------|
|null|null|blabla|13209914|null|null|4|
```

However when I explode like: `select(explode("lorem"))` I do not get the wanted output, instead I get only field 0 and exploded and the other fields except everything inside field4.

**My question is, in what other way should I be flattening this data?**
I can provide a clearer example if needed.

Comment: That is not valid JSON, eg all the quotes are missing.  Does your data actually look like that?  I think if you can spend a bit more effort into making your sample data accurate and provide your expected results (what do you want it to look like after?)  I am sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Edited and added a much better JSON representation of what I'm dealing with

Comment: That's useful, thank you.  I am still not 100% clear on what your expected results should be?  Do you want one row per single property in the JSON, irrespective of whether it's nested or not?  Please add a table which describes your desired output.

Comment: Done! The table is parsed correctly in the preview but not when I post it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withColumn` to add the additional columns you need.  A simple example:

```
%%pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.read.json("abfss://somelake@somestorage.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/flattenJson.json")

df2 = df \
    .withColumn("field4_1", col("field4.field4_1")) \
    .withColumn("field4_2", col("field4.field4_2"))

df2.show()
```

My results:

[image]